# Does the phrase "kindly encouraged me" sound weird or informal?

Tags: formality

Does this sentence:

" you kindly encouraged me"

means you did me a favor by encouraging me? and is this the right way to say such thing in a formal writing?

Comment: In the right context it would be fine:  "When I was feeling defeated you kindly encouraged me."

Comment: 'Kindly' has two very different usages. (1a) sentence adverb: 'He kindly spoke to her' =  'He was so kind: he spoke to her' / (1b) adverb: 'She spoke kindly to him' = 'She spoke to him in a very kind way' // and (2) politeness marker: 'Kindly fasten your seat belts' = 'Please fasten your seat belts'.

Comment: Your sentence has an Indian English ring to it.  Indian English tends to have a lot of deferential and politeness words that are considered excessive or superfluous in American and British English.  "Kindly" fits in the context of Hot Licks comment, but otherwise wouldn't typically be included in that sentence by an American or British speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Did this person speak/write to you personally with encouragement?   If so, then yes...  although it may be better to say;- "Dear So-and-so, 3 months ago at suchandsuch a place, you kindly offered me encouragement to..."    If however, the encouragement was not directly aimed towards you, it may be better to say "Dear So-and-so, 3 months ago you inspired me to ..."  
 See the differences between encourage and inspire.  
  [https://wikidiff.com/encourage/inspire][1]  
 "As verbs, the difference between inspire and encourage is that inspire is to infuse into the mind; to communicate to the spirit; to convey, as by a divine or supernatural influence; to disclose preternaturally; to produce in, as by inspiration while encourage is to mentally support; to motivate, give courage, hope or spirit."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, he wrote me " I encourage you to...". So based on what you said, I believe it is fine to write  "you kindly encouraged me to do...".